# Enabling XMPPMessageCarbons not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I am developing a chat application using [robbiehanson/XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

I am trying to enable Message Carbons for which I am using `XMPPMessageCarbons` from XEP-0280, but I am neither receiving any response nor an error.

Following is my code.

```
XMPPMessageCarbons *xmppMessageCarbon  = [[XMPPMessageCarbons alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

xmppMessageCarbon.autoEnableMessageCarbons = YES;
xmppMessageCarbon.allowsUntrustedMessageCarbons = YES;

[xmppMessageCarbon activate:xmppStream];
```

Please tell me if I am missing out anything or doing it in a wrong way. 
An alternate solution would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for this. I was actually doing it in a wrong way. All I need to do is first call `activate` function and then `enableMessageCarbons`. So the final code will be

```
XMPPMessageCarbons *xmppMessageCarbon  = [[XMPPMessageCarbons alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppMessageCarbon activate:xmppStream];
[xmppMessageCarbon enableMessageCarbons];
```

Comment: Hi could you please guide me how to use XMPPMessageCarbons? I use your code but server doesn't send me response back. Where can I write that code?